# Using Java code to run multiple commands with Runtime/Processbuilder

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to do something very simple here, but it isn't working. 
Basically I have a program and an input file sitting at a certain directory, let's call it "programDir".
I'm writing a plugin in Eclipse that will call this program and run it on the input file.

Essentially two steps must be done: 1) cd to programDir 2) run the program by calling "idp input.txt"

I have done this manually in the cmd and it works as expected. However in Java I can't get it to work. I tried 2 approaches:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+programDir+"\" & \"idp input.txt\"");
```

Here I get the following from the errorStream: "idp output.txt" is not recognized as an intern or extern command, program or batch file

I'm not sure why. I have left out the second part of the command to ensure that I am in the correct location. When i add "start", a console window pops up and it is in the programDir folder. If I then manually type "idp input.txt" I get the expected behavior.

Second approach:

I also used ProcessBuilder after some googling on the subject. I tried this piece of simple code:

```
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "idp input.txt"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.directory(new File(programDir));
    Process proc = pb.start();
```

Now nothing happens and the program does not terminate.
Again, if I add "start" as one of the parameters in "command", a console window pops up in the right location and if I then manually type "idp input.txt", it works. So I have no idea why the code doesn't work.

One interesting thing: the idp.bat file calls a kbs.exe process. When I run the second piece of code, no kbs.exe appears in my task manager. However, as soon as I terminate the program, it briefly makes an appearance. Does that mean my code gets stuck in a loop somewhere or something?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that the quoting is causing cmd.exe think that the executable command is `"idp input.txt"`.Try using "idp.bat" "input.txt".

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot man.